# Taking array input in one line avoiding spaces in python3

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary, replace

Problem: I need to take an array of integers as an input. Extract each integer and store it in a separate array.

My code till now

```
    x = []
    y = []
    x = list(map(int,input()))
    for i in range (len(x)):
      y[i] = x[i]
```

I also tried the replace function but I fail to identify a 2 or 3 digit integer from a single digit integer. Actually this stores 100 as 1,0,0 in a[0],a[1] and a[2] but I need 100 as a single number in a[0].
I need a clear concept about how this works! Can anybody help me out?

Comment: What format are you expecting in the input?

Comment: `x = list(map(int,input()))` should be OK. The rest is unclear.

Comment: @DanielRoseman The input should be in the format: 1 2 3 4 10 11

Comment: you might want to try `list(map(input().split(' ')))`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre The basic problem is I want to extract the integers separately out of the list. So that if I add them up I get a valid result

Comment: @ArcoBas Thanks very much! But map() takes two parameter So the code should be
    list(map(int,input().split(' ')))
Thanks very much everyone!!

Answer (score 1):

The function `.split()` takes a string and return a list of its words. You can specify the separator of the words but by default Python will separate the string by spaces.

For example:

```
x = list(map(int, input().split()))
print(x)
```

if you run this command and input the line:

```
10 8 5
```

You will get as a result:

```
[10, 8, 5]
```

Also, if you want the sum of the numbers, like you said, use the function `sum()` which sums all the elements of a list. This is the program you need:

```
x = sum(map(int, input().split()))
```

Comment: .split doesn't need an argument; by default it will split on whitespace. sum() doesn't need its argument to be a list. A map object works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Since the integers will be separated by spaces, you should use `.split(' ')`.

```
x = list(map(int, input().split(' ')))
```

The rest of your code seems pointless; this one line will be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this on python3 :

```
x = list(map(int, input().split()))
y = list(x)   # will create list y similar to x
print(y)
```

For python2, you can use `raw_input` to do this, something like this :

```
x = list(map(int, str(raw_input()).split()))
y = list(x)   # will create list y similar to x
print(y)
```

For input `100 200`, the result will be :

```
[100, 200]
```

Comment: `y = x` does not create a list similar to `x`; it creates an alias for `x`. If you want to create a new list, use `x[:]`

Comment: That is correct. Reference will be created. Will edit.